# Substitutions not occurring with Typesafe Config

Tags: config, typesafe

When I use Config.withValue to create an updated config, substitutions are not re-evaluated, even with a call to resolve:

application.conf:

```
zooKeeperAddr = "localhost:2181"
zooKeeperAddr2 = ${zooKeeperAddr}
```

Application code:

```
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
                .withValue("zooKeeperAddr", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("abc"))
                .resolve;

  val zooKeeperAddr = config.getAnyRef("zooKeeperAddr")
  val zooKeeperAddr2 = config.getAnyRef("zooKeeperAddr2")
  println(s"zooKeeperAddr, zooKeeperAddr2 is $zooKeeperAddr, $zooKeeperAddr2")
```

I expect, of course, to see

```
 zooKeeperAddr, zooKeeperAddr2 is abc, abc
```

But what I see instead is:

```
 zooKeeperAddr, zooKeeperAddr2 is abc, localhost:2181
```

How can I get substitutions re-evalauted?

(The larger issue is, I'm trying to inject command-line arguments, in particular, Twitter Module Flags, into the Typesafe Config. Perhaps there's a better way to achieve this goal?

My actual code is:

```
    val config = flag.getAll(false).foldLeft(ConfigFactory.load()){
      case (conf, f) if f.isDefined => conf.withValue(f.name, ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(f.get.get))
      case (conf, _) => conf
     }.resolve
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I (the OP) ended up doing the following:

```
  val config = flag.getAll(false).foldLeft(ConfigFactory.empty()){
      case (conf, f) if f.isDefined => conf.withValue(f.name, ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(f.get.get))
      case (conf, _) => conf
    }
    .withFallback(ConfigFactory.defaultOverrides())
    .withFallback(ConfigFactory.defaultApplication())
    .withFallback(ConfigFactory.defaultReference())
    .resolve
```

`flag.getAll` returns an Iterable[com.twitter.app.Flag]; for each flag that  `isDefined`, we add it to an initaily empty config (`ConfigFactory.empty()`).

Then we `withFallback` to, in order, the default overrides (the settings properties), the application config (application.conf, and the default reference (which should include, **I hope**, all reference.confs in all jars).

`withFallback`, according to its documentation, "Returns a new value computed by merging this value with another, with keys in this value "winning" over the other one."

Finally, we `resolve`.

This seems to propagate the substitutions as I want, but I can't help but think the Config API provides an easier way to do this.